# ASP.Net MVC 4 Route/Routing performance issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Performance issue with routing.

The asp.net MVC 4 application takes more time to find the controller itself.

Our project structure for route is area/controller/action/id

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)

{
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default2",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { area = "QQQQQQQ", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
```

unlike the find view this routing takes approximately the same time for all the request(second time , third time and etc)

[image]

Comment: Please do give us some information about your routes - how many, what do they look like, ...

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, i have added the route info in the question

Comment: try to clean your solution and rebuild it again. Because your route seems to be fine

Comment: No it wont help, as the results shown there is from test server, we have daily build but the result is same for couple of months

Comment: can someone give some idea on this

Comment: How do you know it's when its trying to find the controller? And are you using a modified `ControllerFactory`?